# How Can I make this messsage box with just loops and if statements?

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-statements

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjwR.png)

```
        Sub RollerCoaster()

        Dim strCoaster As String
        Dim strType As String
        Dim blnFound As Boolean
        Dim intWood As Integer

        Range("A2").Select


        strType = "Wood"
        blnFound = False


        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        strCoaster = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = strType Then
                strCoaster = ActiveCell.Value
                MsgBox ("The RollerCoaster made out of woods is " & strCoaster)
                blnFound = True
                Exit Do
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Loop

        End Sub
```

I know how to loop for just 1 rollercoaster, but how can I get all the Wood type rollercoaster in a message box?

Comment: "You will loop other RollerCoaster", it means after the loop for strType Wood finish, you will repeat loop for the other strType?

Comment: Can you please show me how i can do that? I kind of have the idea, but i dont know how to apply into VBA

Comment: you want to build up the value that you're storing in `strCoaster`, like this `strCoaster = strCoaster & ActiveCell.value`

Comment: To do that, please change strtype as array, fill your array with your type, first loop the array and then continue perform your do loop as your sample

Comment: I will try to show you here, but only for the additional for your code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (no select/activate required)

```
Sub RollerCoaster()

    Dim strType As String
    Dim c As Range, msg 

    strType = "Wood"
    msg = ""

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") 
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0 = ""
        If c.Offset(0, 2).Value = strType Then
            msg  = msg & vbLf & c.Value
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then Msgbox "Found matches:" & msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here that you ask me to show...

```
 Dim MyType As Variant
 MyType = Array("Wood", "Soil", "Cement", "Brick")
 For mycnt = 1 To UBound(MyType)
     strType = MyType(mycnt - 1)
     blnFound = False
     'Your do loop here
 Next
```